# Restricting data access based on user role in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've the following scenario:
I've employee role, which can add and edit only thier own data. Also there is manager role which can view the data of all employees.
The data is stored in database. Where should I put the validation in this case.

Comment: You can restrict parts of the application using [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware).

Comment: I've restricted the routes with middlewares. However both the manager and the employee should have access to the route for retriving the data. However the returned data must be different for both roles. The employee should retrive all of the records which belong to him and no others. While the manager must have access to all records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-gates) to check if a user has rights to do certain actions. Based on these you can fetch the data that is allowed for this user.

You can create a gate like so:

```
Gate::define('access-all-records', function ($user) {
    return $user->isManager; // Or any other way to find this out
});
```

And fetch data like this:

```
if (Gate::allows('access-all-records')) 
{
    // Fetch all records
}
else
{
    // Fetch data for this user
}
```